# How can I stop GitHub from rendering emojis in Markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to write "H:m:s" in some documentation, but GitHub keeps changing it to "HⓂ️s", since :m: is the code of the Ⓜ️ emoji.

How can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: You can tell GitHub to ignore (or escape) Markdown formatting by using \ before the Markdown character. Read *Ignore markdown formatting* in https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to disable the rendering of an emoji:

1. Use inline code with either `` ` `` or `<code>`, or use 4 spaces before the line to make the whole line monospaced.
2. Insert a zero-width space after the first colon, like this:

   ```
   h:<zero-width space>m:s
   ```

You can copy a zero-width space from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space#Usage).

PS: for text (non-source context) you use the numeric entity representation, `&#8203;`  
(the example results in "h:​m:s").

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but your unnecessary rewrite of the question stopped an upvote.